# Error During Saving a video using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-capture

This is the code to save video from the web cam

```
import numpy  
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object 
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')  
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release() 
out.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I Run It In python it gives the following error

```
> raceback (most recent call last):    File
> "C:\Users\Prakash\Desktop\Image Proccessing\c.py", line 6, in <module>
> fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')  AttributeError: 'module'
> object has no attribute 'VideoWriter_fourcc'
```

Please help me solve this error

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/29648/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-videowriter_fourcc/

Comment: Thank You !!!!! This Link Helped
was using open cv 2.4.9 it dosent support 
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')  function
so replaced it by  fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
and it works FINE

Comment: One of you should post that as an answer and OP should accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python / OpenCV 2.4.9 doesn't support cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc, which is version 3.x.  If you're using 2.4.x:

replace 
`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`

with 
`fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')`

Good example here [How to Record Video Using OpenCV and Python](http://answers.opencv.org/question/27902/how-to-record-video-using-opencv-and-python/)
Reproduced for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # find the webcam
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # video recorder
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')  # cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc() does not exist
    videoOut = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

    # record video
    while (capture.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if ret:
            videoOut.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Video Stream', frame)

        else:
            break

        # Tiny Pause
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    capture.release()
    videoOut.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is answered long ago.

Here is a workaround solution if you met this problem in whatever version.

Refer to "opencv doc":
[https//github.com/opencv/opencv/search?q=CV_FOURCC&unscoped_q=CV_FOURCC](http://https//github.com/opencv/opencv/search?q=CV_FOURCC&unscoped_q=CV_FOURCC)

```
#define CV_FOURCC_MACRO(c1, c2, c3, c4) \
(((c1) & 255) + (((c2) & 255) << 8) + (((c3) & 255) << 16) + (((c4) & 255) << 24))
```

So simply define

```py
def fourcc(a,b,c,d):
    return return ((ord(a) & 255) + ((ord(b) & 255) << 8) + ((ord(c) & 255) << 16) + ((ord(d) & 255) << 24))
```